# What is this yellow substance that came out of a pressure-cooked pork butt?

Tags: pork-shoulder

I pressure-cooked a pork butt tonight,  and this yellow substance was on it. There's no rotten odor, or anything to suggest it'd gone bad. This had never happened to me before.  Can anyone identify it?  Is it safe?

Edit: The other ingredients:  4 New Mexico peppers, 1/2 dried Carolina Reaper pepper, 1 onion,  5 cloves garlic,  12 oz beer, 6 cups water,  6 teaspoons chicken bullion.

[image: pork butt with yellow substance]

Comment: Looks like congealed fat. Can you tell us what you put in there besides the butt?

Comment: Sure thing.  I'll add it in an edit.

Comment: My guess would be congealed fat coloured yellow by the bouillon (and maybe the pepper too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your description of the process and ingredients, and your photo, I agree with bob1's comment that this is congealed pork fat which has been dyed yellow by your chicken bouillon and perhaps also by your peppers.

If that's the case, it's certainly safe to consume although many people remove excess fat which has separated like this (or use it for other purposes like making a roux).

Comment: That is a lot of yellow from 6 teaspoons of bouillon!  But this is the only explanation that makes sense.